# NTLM Node Js получение пользователя

Tags: node.js

Использую express-ntlm для авторизации пользователя. В источниках написано, что функция `app.use(ntlm());` позволяет делать сквозную авторизацию (использовать данные, веденные при входе в систему), но, в любом случае браузер у меня запрашивает логин и пароль системы.

```
var express = require('express'),
ntlm = require('express-ntlm');

var app = express();

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

app.use(ntlm());


app.all('*', function (request, response) {
    response.end(JSON.stringify(request.ntlm)); // {"DomainName":"MYDOMAIN","UserName":"MYUSER","Workstation":"MYWORKSTATION"}
});


app.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Для IE и Chrome это должно быть включено, в свойствах браузера:

[image: IE]

Для FireFox, это делается отдельно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В `trusted-urls` через запятую, без пробелов, должны быть перечислены доверенные сайты.

Comment: Настройки так и стоят, не вариант решения проблемы